# TypeScript: Use keys from Map as type

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I would like to use the keys of a Map as type for a method parameter. The Map has the following keys:

```js
const suffix = new Map<string, string>;
suffix.set("read", "read1");
suffix.set("write", "write1");
suffix.set("delete", "delete1");
suffix.set("admin", "admin1");
```

Currently I'm using the following static structure to get valid parameter values:

```js
getNameExtensionSuffix(type: "read" | "write" | "delete" | "admin"): string {
  if(this.suffix.has(type)) {
    return this.suffix.get(type);
  }
}
```

How to do that to be more dynamic? I would like to be able to add a new key to the Map without being forced to change the method.

Comment: If you want to do it dynamically, taking only keys that are present in the `Map` at the current moment, then `suffix.has(type)` is the only way to do that - there is no type to express this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend declaring an `enum` for the accepted keys for your map, since you would want to restrict it to a subset of strings:

```
enum SuffixKeys {
    READ = 'read',
    WRITE = 'write',
    DELETE = 'delete',
    ADMIN = 'admin',
}

const suffix = new Map<SuffixKeys, string>();
suffix.set(SuffixKeys.READ, "read1");
suffix.set(SuffixKeys.WRITE, "write1");
suffix.set(SuffixKeys.DELETE, "delete1");
suffix.set(SuffixKeys.ADMIN, "admin1");
```

Then, when attempting to retrieve the value from the map, you can do this:

```
getNameExtensionSuffix(type: SuffixKeys): string {
  return suffix.get(type);
}
```

If you have `strictNullChecks` enabled, you will want to coerce the return type as it can potentially be undefined:

```
getNameExtensionSuffix(type: SuffixKeys): string {
  return suffix.get(type) || '';
}
```

...or you can just tell Typescript "I know what I'm doing and it will never be undefined":

```
getNameExtensionSuffix(type: SuffixKeys): string {
  return suffix.get(type)!;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible. The solution is inspired by this [hack](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13086#issuecomment-269695308)

```
interface Map<K,V> {
   set<SK extends K>(key: SK, value: string): TKMap<K, V, SK>;
} 

interface TKMap<K, V, DK> extends Map<K, V> {
    set<SK extends K>(key: SK, value: string): TKMap<K, V, SK | DK>;
    set(key: K, value: V): this;
    set<SK extends K>(key: SK, value: string): TKMap<K, V, SK>;
    get(key: DK): V;
    get(key: K): V | undefined;
}

type KnownKeyosOfTKMap<T> = T extends TKMap< infer K, infer V, infer DK> ? DK : never;

let suffix = new Map<string, string>()
    .set("read", "read1")
    .set("write", "write1")
    .set("delete", "delete1")
    .set("admin", "admin1");

type SuffixKeys = KnownKeyosOfTKMap<typeof suffix>;
// type SuffixKeys = "read" | "write" | "delete" | "admin"
function getNameExtensionSuffix(type: SuffixKeys): string | undefined {
  if(suffix.has(type)) {
    return suffix.get(type);
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this interesting solution, it works but for this simple problem I don't want to extend the default type definitions.

Answer (score 1):

why not define a enum type in ts?
As follow:

```
enum E { A, B }
const keys = Object.keys(E).filter(k => typeof E[k as any] === "number"); // ["A", "B"]
const values = keys.map(k => E[k as any]); // [0, 1]
```

refer:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17198

Answer (score 0):

If any key is fine, they you can just use a string

```
getNameExtensionSuffix(type: string): string {
  ...
}
```

Comment: It should limit the parameter options to the available keys, as stated above. See the updated code sample

Answer (score 0):

one of the ways is to use typescript enums

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html

but since your keys in map may be dynamic, then either you change and add values to your enum at runtime.